# How to calculate the length of the path up to a specific point in a Canvas Android?

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I'm trying to calculate the length of a path up to a given point in a Canvas Android application. I have implemented the following method, but it doesn't seem to be working properly:

```
fun Path.getPathLengthUpToPoint(x: Float, y: Float): Float {
    val pathMeasure = PathMeasure(this.asAndroidPath(), false)
    val pointPosition = floatArrayOf(0f, 0f)
    var distance = pathMeasure.length
    while (pointPosition[1] < y) {
        distance--
        pathMeasure.getPosTan(distance, pointPosition, null)
    }
    return distance
}
```

In my attempt to calculate the length of the path up to a specific point in a Canvas Android application, I implemented a method using a PathMeasure and a loop to iterate backwards along the path. I measured the total length of the path using pathMeasure.length, and then started decrementing the distance while checking the y coordinate of the current point (pointPosition[1]). The intention was to stop the loop when the y coordinate exceeded the desired value.

However, despite implementing this approach, the calculated distance doesn't seem to be accurate. It's possible that there's an error in my implementation or that I missed a crucial step. I'm hoping to receive guidance on what might be causing the incorrect calculation or any alternative approaches to achieve the desired result.

Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
fun Path.getPathLengthUpToPoint(x: Float, y: Float): Float 
{
    if (isEmpty || !isConvex) {
        return -1f 
    }

    val pathMeasure = PathMeasure(this, false)
    var distance = pathMeasure.length
    var step = distance / 2f
    val pointPosition = floatArrayOf(0f, 0f)

    while (step >= 0.1f) { 
        distance -= step
        pathMeasure.getPosTan(distance, pointPosition, null)

        if (pointPosition[1] < y) {
            distance += step
        }

        step /= 2f
    }

    return distance
}
```

This implementation uses a binary search algorithm by successively halving the step size (step) until the desired accuracy is achieved. The threshold of 0.1f in the while loop can be adjusted based on your desired level of accuracy.

Remember to pass the original Path object to the `PathMeasure` constructor instead of `this.asAndroidPath()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun Path.getPathLengthUpToPoint(x: Float, y: Float): Float 
    {
    val pathMeasure = PathMeasure(this, false) 
    val pointPosition = floatArrayOf(0f, 0f)
    val precision = 0.1f //////// Adjust this value for desired precision
    var distance = pathMeasure.length 
    while (pointPosition[1] < y) 
    {
     distance -= precision 
    pathMeasure.getPosTan(distance, pointPosition, null)
     } 
    return distance }
```

decrement distance by smaller value so u can achieve better precision